# Do While Loop not triggering

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use `msoFileDialogFolderPicker` to select a folder and then loop through the folder. I can't seem to get `Do While Len(myFile) > 0` to trigger with `FolderPicker` if I specify`filepath` with `C:\Test\` it works perfectly.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Dim myFile As String, filepath As String
    Dim wbc As Long, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim diaFolder As FileDialog

Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False

If diaFolder.Show = -1 Then
    myFile = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)
End If

    wbc = 0
    filepath = diaFolder

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   'Only try to open xlsm workbooks
    myFile = Dir(filepath & "*.xlsm*")

    Do While Len(myFile) > 0
        'Make sure myFile isn't ThisWorkbook
        If Split(myFile & ".", ".")(0) <> Split(ThisWorkbook.Name & ".", ".")(0) Then

            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filepath & myFile, ReadOnly:=True)

            'Check if there is a Results worksheet
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Results")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not ws Is Nothing Then
                 'Transfer cells B2 & C2 from the results worksheet
                 With ws.Range("A2:B2")
                     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AMT").Range("B4").Offset(wbc, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
                 End With
            End If

            'Close wb most recently opened
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

            wbc = wbc + 1
            If wbc > 1000 Then Exit Do

        End If

        Set ws = Nothing
        myFile = Dir
    Loop

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: You need a trailing slash I think: `myFile = Dir(filepath & "\*.xlsm*")`

Comment: Try using breakpoints/F8 and the `locals window` to see what the actual value of `diaFolder` right before it tries to use it

Comment: 100% need that extra slash

Comment: `myFile = Dir(filepath & "\*.xlsm*")` still has `filepath` = `FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)` Nice suggestion tho!

Comment: Tried the local windows, ` Do While Len(myFile) > 0` = "" then it skips over to the end of the loop `ActiveWorkbook.Save`

Comment: Why `filepath = diaFolder`? The folder is previously stored in `myFile` with `myFile = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)`.  Use `myFile = Dir(myFile & "\*.xlsm*")`

Comment: You might also want to enclose the whole code in the `If diaFolder.Show = -1 Then` test.

Comment: remove the error statement as well, so you can see where the code errors.

Comment: What happens when you single-step (F8) through the code with filepath set to C:\Temp compared to when the filepath is different?

Comment: @peakpeak it works perfectly with a hard coded location. It's the inclusion of the FolderPicker that's been causing this issue.

Comment: Yet, you didn't try to single step? Why?

Comment: @Davesexcel it doesn't error when removing the error statement. It's working correctly but it's showing the location as empty when I'm trying to use the FolderPicker rather than a specific location.

Comment: There you have it. **Now isolate the FolderPicker code** and find out what's happening

Comment: @peakpeak I've single stepped hundreds of times by this point. It's not erroring. I've already said exactly what's occurring. `Do While Len(myFile) > 0` isn't triggering.

Comment: "triggering". Ok you mean that myFile is empty. Then please read my previous comment. That is the way to go

Comment: @peakpeak you've just answered my question by saying "answer your own question". I'm aware myFile is empty, I can't figure out why. That's why I posted in the first place. I've said exactly that in the original post. Thank you for trying, but simply telling me to find out what's happening isn't helping. Nothing is happening, the code is working correctly with our an error coming up. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, that's why I've posted.

Comment: No, you did not isolate (write separate code) to closely examine how FolderPicker works. This is a hint: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it does not work is because you assign myFile to the wrong variable:

Your code:

```
filepath = diaFolder
```

Correct code:

```
filepath = myFile
```

PLUS

```
myFile = Dir(filepath & "*.xlsm*")
```

should be

```
myFile = Dir(filepath & "\*.xlsm")
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped. And your explanation is very useful as well, thank you again.

It's not added the \ between the folder and the file with either  `myFile = Dir(filepath & "*.xlsm*")` or `myFile = Dir(filepath & "\*.xlsm")` it comes up with a cannot be found error but I can see that it's missing the \

Comment: `myFile = Dir(filepath & "\" & "*.xlsm*")` also doesn't work.

Comment: **doesn't work** is not helpful. What is the error message?
Also: Your code corrected as of above works.

Comment: Ok, I've tried and I know I have skills in VBA. I give up because you don't seem to ***engage*** in this matter, you seem to only want working solutions. **I give up**

Comment: you're clearly unable to read and you've condescending the entire time. You don't have to help, so please stop acting like I'm putting you out. I literally said `it comes up with a cannot be found error but I can see that it's missing the \`. I'll try elsewhere, thank you for your time but you don't need to be so patronizing.

Comment: "you're clearly unable to read", yet I'm "condescending". Please! I've given you all the clues and hints you need to resolve your code